# Uncaught ReferenceError: myController is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1 (anonymous) @ VM2169:1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

I'm building an app with Angular and Flask. I can't print `myController` in the console, but I can print `myApp`. The same code works if I just open the `index.html` file.

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello';
    $scope.arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
}]);`
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>This is experiment title</title>
    <h5>This is an experiment.</h5>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <span>This is an experiment, and I'm expecting the data : --greeting--!!</span>
        <br>----------------
        <span ng-repeat='letter in arr'>--This is :{{letter}}--<br></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='angular.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='app/app.js')}}"></script>
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```